# Haskell - add typeclass?

Tags: haskell, operator-overloading, typeclass

Consider the following example:

```
data Dot = Dot Double Double
data Vector = Vector Double Double
```

First, i would like to overload `+` operator for `Vector` addition. If i wanted to overload equality(`==`) operator, i would write it like:

```
instance Eq Vector where ...blahblahblah
```

But I can't find if there is `Add` typeclass to make `Vector` behave like a type with addition operation. I can't even find a complete list of Haskell typeclasses, i know only few from different tutorials. Does such a list exist?

Also, can I overload `+` operator for adding `Vector` to `Dot`(it seems rather logical, doesn't it?).

Comment: Why do you need to distinguish between dots and vectors? As others have mentioned, (+) is in the Num typeclass, but you cannot implement (+) with dots and vectors, since both arguments have to be the same type. If you could think of the two types as being interchangeable, then you could have just one type, and make that type an instance of Num.

Comment: Though you are probably looking for `Num`, the `Monoid` typeclass may also be of interest to you. See, among other resources, [LYAH # monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#monoids)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The operator + in Prelude is defined by the typeclass Num. However as the name suggests, this not only defines addition, but also a lots of other numeric operations (in particular the other arithmetic operators as well as the ability to use numeric literals), so this doesn't fit your use case.

There is no way to overload just + for your type, unless you want to hide Prelude's + operator (which would mean you have to create your own Addable instance for Integer, Double etc. if you still want to be able to use + on numbers).

Comment: I would argue it doesn't really matter if you implement Num and leave all the operators but (+) undefined. In practice, Haskell programmers do sometimes implement typeclasses and leave some methods that they're not going to use undefined.

Answer (score 14):

An easy way to discover information about which typeclass (if any) a function belongs to is to use GHCi:

```
Prelude> :i (+)
class (Eq a, Show a) => Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in GHC.Num
infixl 6 +
```

Answer (score 6):

You can write an `instance Num Vector` to overload `+` for vector addition (and the other operators that make sense).

```
instance Num Vector where
    (Vector x1 y1) + (Vector x2 y2) = Vector (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2)
    -- and so on
```

However, note that `+` has the type `Num a => a -> a -> a`, i.e. both operands and the result all have to be the same type. This means that you cannot have a `Dot` plus a `Vector` be a `Dot`.

While you can hide `Num` from the `Prelude` and specify your own `+`, this is likely to cause confusion and make it harder to use your code together with regular arithmetic.

I suggest you define your own operator for vector-point addition, for example

```
(Dot x y) `offsetBy` (Vector dx dy) = Dot (x + dx) (y + dy)
```

or some variant using symbols if you prefer something shorter.

Comment: There's nothing *wrong* with hiding `(+)`, or all of `Num`, and using your own instead. The problem is that to do so as anything other than a really ugly hack, you basically end up being forced to replace most of the Prelude's numeric classes completely.

Answer (score 4):

I sometimes see people defining their own operators that kind of look like ones from the Prelude. Even `++` probably uses that symbol because they wanted something that conveyed the idea of "adding" two lists together, but it didn't make sense for lists to be an instance of `Num`. So you could use `<+>` or `|+|` or something.